# iTextSharp get coordinates of

Tags: itext

I saw this 8+ years old post, but I'm hoping iTextSharp version 5.x has this feature by now? I can't find anything that says they do but still posting my question to this in the hope of it.

[itextsharp: getting coordinates of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911235/itextsharp-getting-coordinates-of-image?answertab=active#tab-top)

From an existing PDF file, I'd like to find the (x, y) coordinates on a page of QR codes from the sample code here. Also, I'd like to find the (x, y) of certain text string on a page. Is it doable?

If not, do you know of any other PDF framework that can do this?
I've started looking into TallComponents, but I'm hoping for a free open source.

Thanks.

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(memStream))
{
    for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
    {
        PdfDictionary page = pdfReader.GetPageN(pageIndex);
        PdfDictionary resources = page.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);
        PdfDictionary xobjects = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);

       if (xobjects != null)
       {
           foreach (var item in xobjects.Keys)
           {
               PRStream origStream = (PRStream)xobjects.GetAsStream(item);
               var pdfImage = new PdfImageObject(origStream);

               var qrCodeInfo = IsImageQrCode(pdfImage);
               if (qrCodeInfo != null)
               {
                   // Find the (x, y) coordinates of pdfImage.
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: We don't talk about iTextSharp anymore. iTextSharp was renamed to iText for .NET, and the current version is iText 7. The answer to your question can be found in the FAQ on the official web site: [How to get the co-ordinates of an image?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/content-parsing-extraction-and-redaction-text/itext7-how-get-co-ordinates-image) If you really want an iText 5 solution, take a look at the duplicate question I used to close your question.

Comment: By the way: your code is illogical. You search a PDF for images, then you try to get the coordinates of each image. However, imagine a logo that occurs multiple times in a document, on multiple locations in multiple pages. In that case, you wouldn't get an `x` and `y` value, but an array of `pagenumber`, `x` and `y` values.

Comment: Also note that you mention QR codes. If done well, the QR Codes aren't stored in the PDF as a raster image. Hence they will never be detected as an image object. Good QR codes consist of vector data that was created using PDF syntax. If that's the case, you'll need to parse the PDF syntax of every page, and it will be extremely hard to find that particular piece of syntax that is responsible for drawing the QR code. That's probably a couple of months worth of work.

Comment: Finally: you should never write something like this in a Stack Overflow question: *If not, do you know of any other PDF framework that can do this? I've started looking into TallComponents, but I'm hoping for a free open source.* Questions asking to recommend software are off-topic on Stack Overflow (see the FAQ) and *I'm hoping for a free open source* is ambiguous, because you don't explain is you mean free as in FOSS or free as in free of charge. Free Open Source Software is about freedom, not about price. Open source doesn't mean the software is *for free*.

Comment: This sample code is from iText's docs, so I don't know why you say it's illogical. So, what if an image or logo exists 1 or 100s times on a page/doc? That's what I want, to find the location of each image that can be anywhere in the PDF, and by images, in this case, I mean QR codes.

Comment: You're right about QR codes can be saved as vector data, but they can also be saved as images too, e.g. when converting Word to PDF, and this is something we'll require in our app for QR codes to be read from the provided PDF files.

Comment: I've started with iText5, and it seems iText7's syntax is all different, so I was trying to stay with 5 if it can provide what I'm looking for. As for the licenses, I'm sorry I was looking at different things yesterday and for the heck of me I thought iText7 wasn't an AGPL.

Comment: Will probably hit you with more questions on this when I get a chance to take a look at your samples. Thanks.